# Conflict of dependencies updating laravel project from 5.8 to 6.0

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upgrade my project step by step but when i ran composer update i gotch a lot of errors about nesbot/carbon.

```
 Problem 1
    - illuminate/database[v5.4.0, ..., 5.4.x-dev] require nesbot/carbon ~1.20 -> found nesbot/carbon[1.20.0, ..., 1.39.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.0 -> found nesbot/carbon[1.26.0, ..., 1.39.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev requires nesbot/carbon 1.26.* -> found nesbot/carbon[1.26.0, ..., 1.26.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.6.11] require nesbot/carbon ^1.20 -> found nesbot/carbon[1.20.0, ..., 1.39.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support[v5.5.40, ..., v5.7.1] require nesbot/carbon ^1.24.1 -> found nesbot/carbon[1.24.1, ..., 1.39.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support v5.6.39 requires nesbot/carbon 1.25.* -> found nesbot/carbon[1.25.0, 1.25.1, 1.25.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - illuminate/support[v5.7.2, ..., 5.7.x-dev] require nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> found nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, ..., 1.39.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/database[v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/database and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - spatie/laravel-permission[2.36.0, ..., v2.x-dev] require illuminate/database ~5.4.0|~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
    - illuminate/database[v5.5.0, ..., 5.5.x-dev] require illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.5.x-dev].
    - illuminate/database[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev] require illuminate/support 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev].
    - illuminate/database[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev] require illuminate/support 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-permission ^2.36 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-permission[2.36.0, ..., v2.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 6.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4].
```

if i put nesbot/carbon in 1.39.1 and run composer update --with-all-dependencies i get this

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4] require nesbot/carbon ^2.0 -> found nesbot/carbon[dev-master, 2.0.0-beta.1, ..., 2.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.39.1).
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 6.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4].
```

thats my original composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The base system in Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "^0.4.2",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.26",
        "crazybooot/base64-validation": "^1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.8",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "dymantic/laravel-instagram-feed": "^2.4",
        "eluceo/ical": "^0.16.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "ixudra/curl": "^6.16",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "needim/noty": "^3.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.22",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^9.2",
        "pagarme/pagarme-php": "^4.0",
        "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "^1.0",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
        "spatie/laravel-model-status": "^1.9",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^0.7.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "laravel/telescope": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.2",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "1.0.1",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.36",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7",
        "uxweb/sweet-alert": "^2.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tryied to change de depencies to solve the problem but came on a loop of errors

Comment: Check on packagist.org the required versions for your packages and laravel 6. spatie/permissions should be ^3.0, I believe, but really, check there.

Comment: You must upgrade `nesbot/carbon` to `^2`, the `1.x` version is old, deprecated, and not used anymore by laravel since v6.x

Comment: @matiaslauriti in the first error is if i put in ^2, They conflict with laravel already installed  illuminate

Comment: @DiegoPedro do you tried to 'composer install'?

Comment: @DiegoPedro did you try setting all dependencies to nee versions and use `composer install --withhallhdependencies`? You could also try `composer update` and also try removing the `composer.lock` and `composer install`

Comment: @DiegoPedro the command is `--update-with-all-dependencies`